# How to find a reputable open access journal?

Tags: publishers, open-access

I found few open access journals that show quite good quality articles. However, I have been advised that open access journals may be predatory. When I searched websites, I was surprised that all lists are "possibly" predatory journals. I tried to figure out why these lists are "possibly" predatory. One of the answers is that the websites claiming predatory publishers attempt to avoid judicial consequences. On the other hand, I also found that editors from the conventional publishers could have conflict of interests with competing open access publishers. I am completely puzzled and do not know if these lists of "possibly" predatory journals are due to conflict of interests or due to commercial interest of the open access journals. I want to publish my research paper timely and do not know if I should choose an open access journal. And, if yes, then how to find a reputable open access journal? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Use a journal that is indexed in the [DOAJ](https://doaj.org/) (Directory of Open Access Journals).

The DOAJ has a certain quality check regarding the journals' trustworthiness, and it thoroughly reviews journals marked as 'questionable' by users ([see, for instance, their FAQ](https://doaj.org/faq#predatory)).

Comment: Thank you for the DOAJ! I will read it carefully.